# Smooth letter-spacing transition on other browsers

Tags: css, transition, letter-spacing

I'm using the following to animate a hover transition:

```
a {
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
a {
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

[Here is a jsBin.](http://jsbin.com/meweci/1/edit)

At first I didn't expect this to be pretty but was pleasantly surprised when I saw how smoothly it was animated in Chrome. Even though it only changes 1px in the spacing, somehow Chrome gives the illusion of a smooth transition.

In Safari though it just jumps from 1px to 2px without that nice smoothing effect.

Is there any way to get the same effect in Safari?

(Alternatively, is there a CSS-only way of disabling this in non-Chrome browsers?)

Comment: Looks fine in Firefox for me... Safari *is* jumpy though

Comment: @misterManSam My bad my eyes must have been betraying me, just double checked and that jsBin example posted does work fine on Firefox. Can confirm it's ugly on Safari though. Edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mis-read the entry for `letter-spacing` in the [list of CSS Animated properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). In actual fact, any type of length unit is able to be used with the `letter-spacing` animation. It appears that Safari doesn't smoothly animate a 1 pixel difference - a bug.

The solution for small letter-spacing animations cross-browser is the use of `em` units and also a smaller delay of `.1s` to get a smooth transition. Safari does not have as smooth an animation for *small* `letter-spacing` animations, but it is passable.

[Updated example jsBin with an em unit](http://jsbin.com/nuqayo/1/edit) (Tested and working in Safari, Firefox, Chrome)

CSS

```
a {
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 transition: all .1s ease-in;
}
a:hover {
 letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}
```

Available browser prefixes (if needed):

```
-webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all .1s ease-in;
-ms-transition: all .1s ease-in;
-o-transition: all .1s ease-in;
transition: all .1s ease-in;
```

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation and works on Safari now but for some reason on Firefox 31 on OS X my letter-spacing transition just wont work, even with all the vendor prefixes and using `em`s. If it's not too much to ask and if you have a minute could you see if you can pinpoint the issue? http://rlcoaching.com/rl   Works fine on Safari and Chrome now those fixes though.

Comment: I'm afraid that with a quick look I can't pinpoint the problem. Try removing all your other transitions and just use `transition: all .5s ease-in;` exactly. If that works then add your other transitions one by one and see what breaks it.

Comment: Thank you for your help and giving it a try!

Answer (score 2):

to disable it, use your code like this:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
a {
letter-spacing: 1px;
transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
a {
letter-spacing: 2px;
}
}
```

this will disable your code in any non-webkit browser (thus, will only work in Chrome and Safari). Other than that, your code works fine, Webkit has just better smoothing engine, nothing else, but Firefox and IE handle it without issues, so really don't know what are you seeing in terms of differences